# Setting a new id for each button press using javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I make a button using javascript that makes a new div element with a new id each time the button is pressed.
This is what I want the html to look like. But I want it to be made with javascript.

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
```

I am a new self taught coder so be gentle please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a element using `document.createElement()` method, then set it's id by `id` property and then append it to the DOM, in this case I appended the element to the `body`.

```js
var element = document.createElement("DIV");
element.id = "4";
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Here is an example of generating an element on button click with new id each time:

```js
var base = 0;

function addElement() {
  base++
  var element = document.createElement("DIV");
  element.id = base;
  element.innerHTML = base
  document.body.appendChild(element)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addElement()">Add element!</button>
```

Comment: I was thinking a new id each click rather than the same id like how I showed it would make.

Comment: @AlasdairPirie I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @AlasdairPirie you are welcome, I would appreciate if you would accept this answer using the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

```
var base = 0;

function addElement() {
 base++
 var element = document.createElement("DIV");
 element.id = base;
 element.innerHTML = base
 document.body.appendChild(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a static id variable to keep track of the generated incremented number.

For the div generation, you can use the document.createElement method which creates the HTML element specified by tagName (div in your case)

```js
let id = 0;

function createDiv(){
  var element = document.createElement("DIV");
  element.id = id;
  element.textContent = id;
  id++;

  document.body.appendChild(element)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createDiv()">Add div</button>
```